# Formatting a long json text from wordpress in android

Tags: android, json, wordpress, format

Am getting a long json text in my android app from wordpress and I want to format it to have paragraph, because the text has bullets like this 1,2,3, so i need the text to display in bullets like this

1........

2.......

3.......

This is how am getting it in json
  public class Didyouknow extends SherlockListActivity {

```
private ActionBarMenu abm;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://www.cepfonline.org/features/dyk/?json=1";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_QUERY = "posts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";


// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray query = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> queryList;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upcoming);

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    abm = new ActionBarMenu(Didyouknow.this);

    if (com.cepfmobileapp.org.service.InternetStatus.getInstance(this).isOnline(this)) {

       // Toast t = Toast.makeText(this,"You are online!!!!",8000).show();
       // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"You are online",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetQuery().execute();

    } else {
        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       //Toast t = Toast.makeText(this,"You are not online!!!!",8000).show();
       // Log.v("Home", "############################You are not online!!!!"); 
         AlertDialog NetAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Didyouknow.this).create();
            NetAlert.setMessage("No Internet Connection Found! Please check your connection and try again!");
            NetAlert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                   //here you can add functions
                     // finish();

                } });
            NetAlert.show();
       }

    queryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            //String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();

            //String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();

            //String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity
            /*Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleContactActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
            startActivity(in);*/

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    //new GetQuery().execute();
}

private String parseHtml(String html){
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    return doc.text();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetQuery extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Didyouknow.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                query = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_QUERY);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < query.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = query.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String content = c.getString(TAG_CONTENT);
                    //String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    //String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                    contact.put(TAG_CONTENT, parseHtml(content));
                    //contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    queryList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
```

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Didyouknow.this, queryList,   R.layout.list_itemup,    new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_CONTENT}, new int[] { R.id.title,
                            R.id.content });

```
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you have html in that string, why not use Html.fromHtml() to turn it into a spannable based on the markup?

Comment: please can you kindly edit the code for me please, am not sure how to do this